# Mappear HTTP requests de un dominio a una IP específica

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

Quiero poder implementar un mockserver o mockapi al que pueda hacer peticiones  con nombres de dominio, y poder crear stubs sobre las llamadas.

Por ejemplo, un programa que sea algo como:

```py
mock_response = fake_requests.get("google.com")  // Mock request
mock_response.json()  // Mock response
```

Pero que 1) O mapee el dominio google a otra IP (e.g. 127.0.0.1), o 2) Dé un mock response.

Para esto se me han ocurrido varias estrategias:

1. Hacer un mokeypatch de la biblioteca *requests* sobre los metodos *get*, *post*, etc
2. Utilizar alguna librería de mockservers
3. Crear mi propio clon de requests para lo que necesito
4. Modificar el archivo de resolución de direcciones de mi equipo

El problema con estas opciones es que:

1. Es muy sucio y los resultados de otros metodos podrían ser inesperados
2. No todas tiene soporte y muchas solo son para tests
3. Me parece la más sencilla y viable, pero quizáse sea demasiado costosa la implementacion de ciertos mecanismos y propiedades como lectura de cookies, el manejo de los metodos, el body, headers, y demás cosas
4. No se me ocurre como podría hacerlo portable e interoperable, ya que lo tendría que hacer en cada equipo en el quiera correr el programa. Quizás dockerizando la aplicación y el archivo de resolución de direcciones

El objetivo de esto es crear un ambiente artificial donde pueda emular el comportamiento de un API.

Actualmente lo único que tengo es un servidor corriendo una aplicación de Flask en background, pero este servicio local usa la IP para recibir llamadas (por ejemplo, 127.0.0.1), pero me interesa que en lugar de la pura IP, se pueda simular una llamada a cualquier nombre de dominio.

Mi implementación está en este repositorio: https://gitlab.com/mrc_es/python_interview/-/blob/master/python/second_app/app.py

Donde las líneas:

```
all_books_url: str = f"http://{config.host_name}:{config.port}/v2/all_books"  # [Interview]: F'strings
put_authors_url: str = f"http://{config.host_name}:{config.port}/v2/save_authors"
```

Solo usan la IP del mock API, cuando yo quiero poder usar cualquier nombre de dominio para simular la llamada a una API.

Comment: Y cuál es el objetivo de esto?

Comment: @Fedex7501 Listo, actualizado

Comment: Pues la solución más sencilla es comprar un dominio XD. Lo digo porque ninguna de las opciones que diste te parece óptima y dudo que haya una solución mejor. Aquí en Argentina el NIC vende dominios `.ar` a 1 USD

Comment: Buenísima idea idea, no se me había ocurrido. Pero solo tendría acceso a un solo nomber de dominio (el que compre). Yo quisiera o 1) Mapear el que sea a una IP, o 2) Hacer un fake response de la llamada a ese dominio.

Comment: En Java es posible con una cosa creo que llamada MockServer.

Comment: De hecho gracias a la magia del DNS puedes tener tantos subdominios como quieras. Igual te deseo suerte para encontrar lo que buscas.

Comment: Gracias, justo esa es la cuarta opción, pero no es portable.

Comment: Mmm no. No me refiero a la resolución de direcciones dentro del equipo. Me refiero a que si compras un dominio puedes redirigir cada subdominio a una IP diferente. Osea puedes tener `midominio.mx`, `api.midominio.mx`, `test.api.midominio.mx`, etc... Osea que 1 se convierte en infinitos si no te molesta que el dominio principal sea el mismo. Y esa resolución la maneja el servidor de DNS osea que sí es portable.

Comment: La cosa es que el nombre de dominio que tenga, ese será y no otro hasta que lo compre. Lo que busco es que suceda con cualquier nombre de dominio.